# Updating a Cloud function and currently running functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

What happens to the currently running Firebase Cloud functions when you update it?
Does it stop immediately or wait until finished?
Will the user notice anything (errors) when a function that he has called (http) is updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No function executions will be interrupted at the time of deployment.

Comment: How do you generally deal with that? Do the functions return an error if they get interrupted will executed? Thank you very much for your help

Comment: I am actually reading again your reply and I am wondering where the "No" refers to. Do you mean that "none function executions.." or "function executions will be interrupted.."

Comment: Function executions are never interrupted.